# Using if statement inside for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript For Loop...

```
var CookieName = "Tab,EduTab,EduTab,user";
var tString = CookieName.split(',');

for(i = 0; i < tString.length; i++){

    if (tString[i] == "EduTab") {
        document.write("<b>"+tString[i]+"<b>"); 
    } else {
        document.write(tString[i]);
    }
}
```

For some reason it is failing to bold the 'EduTab'. It will either bold the entire array CookieName or none at all. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't closing the `<b>` tag

```
document.write("<b>"+tString[i]+"<b>")
```

should be

```
document.write("<b>"+tString[i]+"</b>")
```

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the `/`  in your closing tab   `</b>`